# Opening phone apps through button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have about 12 buttons that each button opens phone apps by it's name.
Now i can open messages and phone call but for other ones i don't know what should i put.
This is my code for phone call:

```
        phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent phonecall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            phonecall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));
            startActivity(phonecall);
        }
    });
```

"tel:" will open phone call, now i want to know what should i put in "tel:" for other apps, Here's my other buttons need to open:
Camera, Contacts, Browser, File Manager, Settings, Gallery, Clock, Telegram application, Instagram application, Whatsapp application.

Comment: i don't think do you really understand implicit intents, you're not opening an app, you're opening an app which can make phone calls, you can't open any app like that by name

Comment: so what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a part of Implicit Intent.

If you want the Android system to handle the intent for a particular task, you can use this.

```
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Constants.CALL_CENTER_NUMBER));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

Example: You can fire an `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` or `Intent.ACTION_CALL` without specifying any particular package name to handle this and Android system will handle this intent.

If you want your intent to be handled by a particular application then you can specify the package name of the application.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity( launchIntent );
```

Comment: I don't want to share any text or do any task i just want that when i click on whatsapp button whatsapp open or if i click on contacts or gallery button contacts or gallery app open. just open that's it

Comment: @Captain.Andreas  instead of copy pasting the code learn learn about intents -> https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters and https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending